# Perl Compare hash of arrays with another array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hashmap, compare

I am trying to compare all the array values (complete array) with a hash's value(which is array) and if the match founds,then push the key of hash to new array.
The below code compare if the hash value is not array but how can I compare if its array?

```
%hash=(
       storeA=>['milk','eggs'],
       storeB=>['milk','fruits','eggs','vegetables'],
       storeC=>['milk','fruits','eggs'],
      );

@array = (
        'fruits',
        'milk',
        'eggs'
    );
```

Code to compare

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

foreach my $thing (@array)   {
     foreach ((my $key, my $value) = each %hash)   { 
                 if ($value eq $thing)   {
                       push @new_array, $key;
                }
          }
   }
  print Dumper(\@new_array);
```

**Expected Output**

```
@new_array = (
               storeB,
               storeC
       );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a hash out of each store's stock array. It's a wasteful method, but not egregiously so as long as the real data isn't enormous

Like this. The inner `grep` statement counts the number of items in `@list` that are available at this store and compares it to the number of items in the list, returning *true* if everything is in stock

If this is a real situation (I suspect it's homework) then for all practical purposes that I can think of, the `%stocks` hash should contain *hashes* of the items available at each store

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %stocks = (
    storeA => [ qw/ milk eggs / ],
    storeB => [ qw/ milk fruits eggs vegetables / ],
    storeC => [ qw/ milk fruits eggs / ],
);

my @list = qw/ fruits milk eggs /;

my @stores = grep {
    my %stock = map { $_ => 1 } @{ $stocks{$_} };
    grep($stock{$_}, @list) == @list;
} keys %stocks;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@stores;
```

#### output

```
["storeB", "storeC"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a combination of `all` and `any` form [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) :

```
while ((my $key, my $value) = each %hash) {
    if ( all { my $temp = $_; any { $_ eq $temp } @$value } @array ) {  
        push @new_array, $key;
    }
}
```

So here you are looking for the case where all the elements of `@array` exists in the given array from the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Find the intersection of the two sets, if the number of its elements is the number of the elements in the array, you want to store the key:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


sub intersect {
    my ($arr1, $arr2) = @_;
    my %intersection;
    $intersection{$_}{0}++ for @$arr1;
    $intersection{$_}{1}++ for @$arr2;
    return grep 2 == keys %{ $intersection{$_} }, keys %intersection
}


my %hash = (
            storeA => [qw[ milk eggs ]],
            storeB => [qw[ milk fruits eggs vegetables ]],
            storeC => [qw[ milk fruits eggs ]],
           );

my @array = qw( fruits milk eggs );

my @new_array;

while (my ($store, $arr) = each %hash) {  # while, not for!
    push @new_array, $store if @array == intersect(\@array, $arr);
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this. One small trick i done here.  [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) was use to filter the element from an array.

I created the variable `$joined_array` which contain the `|` separated `@array` data. Then i pass the variable into the grep.

And the trick is, when the array is compare with a scalar data, the comparison is behave, the total number of an array element with scalar data.

```
my @array = qw(one two three);

if(@array == 3)
{
    print "Hi\n";

}
```

Here condition is internally run as `3 == 3`.

That the same logic i done here.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my %hash=(
    "storeA"=>['milk','eggs'],
    "storeB"=>['milk','fruits','eggs','vegetables'],
    "storeC"=>['milk','fruits','eggs'],
);

my @array = (
    'fruits',
    'milk',
    'eggs'
);

my @new_array;

my $joined_array = join("|",@array);

foreach (keys  %hash)
{

 push(@new_array,$_) if  ((grep{ /\b$joined_array\b/ } @{$hash{$_}}) >= scalar @array);

}

print "$_\n" for @new_array
```

Comment: A nice idea, but if `storeC` stocked `eggshells` then it would fulfill `eggs` on the list. It would also be better to use `@array` instead of `3`, as it expresses the meaning as well as the value, and also continues to work if the contents of `@array` are changed. And I wonder why you've chosen to put the constant first in the comparison? It's not wrong at all, but it's very uncommon to use `3 <= $expression` rather than `$expression >= 3`.

Comment: Oh, and I wouldn't go changing the values of built-in variables like `$,`, especially without wrapping the associated code in a block and using `local`. No one remembers what they do, and `print "$_\n" for @new_array` is fine here

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for your helpful comment post edited. I used word bountry  `\b`  for matching. And then reason for `>= 3` is some time hash of array value contain repeated data something like ` storeB=>['milk','fruits','eggs','vegetables','milk]` my condition will satisfy, `==3` won't satisfy for the above data. :).

Comment: I'm not clear about your reasoning for using `>=`. `grep` will always return the number of elements in the array if they all match, regardless of duplicates. `perl -E 'say scalar grep /a/, qw/ a a a a/'` prints 4

Comment: @Borodin Consider for example `storeB=>['milk','fruits','eggs','vegetables','milk]`  now grep results the value `4`.  If `3==4` means not satisfied.  So i put the `>=`.

Comment: Ah! I understand. Sorry for being dim.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all stores (keys) and for each check whether all array elems are in the key's array-ref.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %inventory = (
    storeA => ['milk','eggs'],
    storeB => ['milk','fruits','eggs','vegetables'],
    storeC => ['milk','fruits','eggs'],
);    
my @items = ('fruits', 'milk', 'eggs');

my @found;
foreach my $store (keys %inventory) {
    push @found, $store 
        if @items == grep { in_store($_, $inventory{$store}) } @items
}   

sub in_store { for (@{$_[1]}) { return 1 if $_[0] eq $_ }; return 0; }

print "@found\n";  # prints:  storeB storeC
```

The `grep` block checks for each item whether it is (available) in the store, and if the number of those that pass is equal to the number of items (array size) that store has all items and is added.  Note that a subroutine returns the last value evaluated without an explicit return, so the final `return` is not needed.  It was added for clarity.

Comment: Or,  `sub in_store { $_[0] eq $_ and return 1  for @{$_[1]} }`